# How to draw parentheses inside chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

I have the following code:

```
\chemfig[][scale=0.6]{
  CH_2=[:-30]CH-[:30]C(=[:90]O)-[:-30]O-[:30]CH_2CH_2-[:-30]O-[:30]C(=[:90]O)-[:-30]CH=[:30]CH_2
}
```

Which gives me this image:

[image]

Now I want to draw openening parentheses between O-CH_2CH_2 and closing parentheses between O-C. And to subindex the closing parentheses with an n. How can I achieve that? Do I have to use `tikzpicture` environement or the `\leftdelimiter(`. The problems I'm facing are alignment and length of the connector.

EDIT

I have some additional figure, how could I achieve the brackets in this case?

```
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}

\def\makebraces(#1,#2)#3#4#5{%
  \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
  \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
  \chemmove{
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
       \left\delimleft
         \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
       \right.
      $};
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
        \left.
          \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
        \right\delimright_{\rlap{#3}}
      $};
  }%
}
\setpolymerdelim[]
\chemfig[][scale=0.6]{
  ?(-[2]CH_2-[@{op,.8}:180,3])(-[::-30,1.5]O-[::+60](-[:-30,1.5]O-[@{cl,.8}:0,3])<[::-150,1.5](-[:-50]O(-[7](=[6]O)-[1](-[7]CH_3)=[8]CH_2))-[::-90,1.5,,,line width=3pt](-[:45,1.5]OH)>[::+60]?(-[:-120]OH))
}
\makebraces(50pt,50pt){$\scriptstyle\!\!n$}{op}{cl}
```

And the image:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An example for this is given in the [documentation of `chemfig`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/chemfig) (part III section 12.5 *Draw polymer element*). There a macro

```
\makebraces(<dim up>,<dim down>){<subscript>}{<opening node name>}{<closing node name>}
```

is defined that exploits `chemfig`'s `@{<node name>,<pos>}` syntax inside formulas to position delimiters on a bond.

The code below is basically a copy from there:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}

\def\makebraces(#1,#2)#3#4#5{%
  \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
  \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
  \chemmove{
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
       \left\delimleft
         \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
       \right.
      $};
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
        \left.
          \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
        \right\delimright_{\rlap{#3}}
      $};
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\setpolymerdelim()
\chemfig{
  CH_2=[:-30]CH-[:30]C(=[:90]O)-[:-30]O
    -[@{op,.75}]CH_2CH_2-[@{cl,.25}]
    O-[:30]C(=[:90]O)-[:-30]CH=[:30]CH_2
}
\makebraces(5pt,5pt){$\!\!n$}{op}{cl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first part of `\makebraces(<dim up>,<dim down>)` specifies the height of the parentheses (divided in an *up* and *down* part). The parentheses can be positioned via the `<pos>` part of `@{<node name>,<pos>}`. The fontsize can be changed in the `<subscript>` part of `\makebraces`. It could also be hardcoded in the macro itself, of course.

```
\setpolymerdelim()
\chemfig{
  -[@{op,.75}:30]CH_2CH_2-[:-30]O-[@{cl,.5}:30]
}
\makebraces(12pt,12pt){$\scriptstyle\!\!n$}{op}{cl}
```

[image]

To be more flexible one could change the definition of `\makebraces` to get different upper and lower height for each parenthesis.

**Edit in response to edited question**:

The code below is a quick modification of the `\makebraces` command that makes the argument `(<dim up>,<dim down>)` optional and sets both to `5pt` as default for both delimiters. It also introduces a second optional `(<dim up>,<dim down>)` that when used sets different values for the closing delimiter. For convenience this is done with the help of [`xparse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse). This allows for better control of both delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}

\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@set@open@delim[2]{%
  \edef\open@delim@halfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2\relax}%
  \edef\open@delim@vshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2\relax}%
}
\newcommand\@set@close@delim[2]{%
  \edef\close@delim@halfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2\relax}%
  \edef\close@delim@vshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2\relax}%
}
\newcommand\@make@braces[3]{%
  \chemmove{
    \node[at=(#2),yshift=(\open@delim@vshift)]
      {$
       \left\delimleft
         \vrule height\open@delim@halfdim depth\open@delim@halfdim width0pt
       \right.
      $};
    \node[at=(#3),yshift=(\close@delim@vshift)]
      {$
        \left.
          \vrule height\close@delim@halfdim depth\close@delim@halfdim width0pt
        \right\delimright_{\rlap{#1}}
      $};
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\makebraces
  {
    >{ \SplitArgument{1}{,} } D(){5pt,5pt}
    >{ \SplitArgument{1}{,} } d()
    mmm
  }
  {%
    \@set@open@delim #1%
    \IfNoValueTF {#2}
      {\@set@close@delim#1}
      {\@set@close@delim#2}%
    \@make@braces{#3}{#4}{#5}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setpolymerdelim[]
\chemfig[][scale=0.6]{
  ?(-[2]CH_2-[@{op,.8}:180,3])(-[::-30,1.5]O-[::+60](-[:-30,1.5]O-[@{cl,.8}:0,3])<[::-150,1.5](-[:-50]O(-[7](=[6]O)-[1](-[7]CH_3)=[8]CH_2))-[::-90,1.5,,,line width=3pt](-[:45,1.5]OH)>[::+60]?(-[:-120]OH))
}
\makebraces(10pt,100pt)(46pt,64pt){$\scriptstyle\!\!n$}{op}{cl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what I was searching (didn't found it in the docs). There are some issues left: how can I change the fontsize of the small n and how can I shift the brackets in y-axis when I'm using them for connections other then 0 degree. Is there a way to align them?

Comment: @Reza see edited answer

Answer (score 5):

The use of `\rlap` and `\llap` seems much easier in this case since there is no need to copy and adapt a complex macro:

```
\def\leftparen{\llap{$\left(\strut\right.$\kern5pt }}
\def\rightparen{\rlap{$\kern5pt \left.\strut\right)_n$}}
\chemfig{
    CH_2=[:-30]CH-[:30]C(=[:90]O)-[:-30]O
    -[:30]\leftparen CH_2CH_2|\rightparen
    -[:-30]O-[:30]C(=[:90]O)-[:-30]CH=[:30]CH_2
}
```

which gives

[image: chemfig paren]

That said, I'm not sure the right bracket is where the OP wants...

**EDIT** Always complicated, Clemens... You can do something simple which does not require the complicated `xparse` package:

```
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}

\def\makebraces(#1,#2)#3#4#5{%
  \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
  \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
  \chemmove{%
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {\rlap{$
       \left\delimleft
         \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
         \kern#5
       \right\delimright_{#3}$}%
      };%
}}
\setpolymerdelim[]
\chemfig[][scale=0.6]{
  ?(-[2]CH_2-[@{op,.8}:180,3])(-[::-30,1.5]O-[::+60](-[:-30,1.5]O-[:0,3])<[::-150,1.5](-[:-50]O(-[7](=[6]O)-[1](-[7]CH_3)=[8]CH_2))-[::-90,1.5,,,line width=3pt](-[:45,1.5]OH)>[::+60]?(-[:-120]OH))
}
\makebraces(5pt,90pt){n}{op}{130pt}
```

and the result is
[image]

Comment: You're right, he wanted it somewhere else (I missed that...). But it shouldn't be too hard to change either example to adapt. What I like better about the way given in the documentation is that once defined it's easy to apply to various different kinds of molecules. A document about polymers often has more than one of them.

Comment: Nice idea, I _should_ have thought of a horizontal shift! :). Although I wouldn't call `xparse` complicated

Comment: xparse, not complicated??? Funny. I guess you probably have not read the code. In my opinion, I would call this package a very complicated thing. In this case, `\kern` and `\rlap` are more intuitive and simple.

Comment: Ah, this has been a misunderstanding :). I did not mean the package code but the user interface... But I agree for the example at hand the horizontal shift is definitely easier.

Comment: Yes I like your solution, exactly what I was looking for.