# Fine tuning parentheses inside chemfig

Tags: delimiters, chemfig

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}

%these for bonds in chemfig
\setdoublesep{0.35700 em}  % 'Bond Spacing'
\setatomsep{1.78500 em}    % 'Fixed Length'
\setbondoffset{0.18265 em} % 'Margin Width'
\newcommand{\bondwidth}{0.06642 em} % 'Line Width'
\setbondstyle{line width = \bondwidth}

%Drawing parentheses around polymers
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}

\def\makebraces(#1,#2)#3#4#5{%
  \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
  \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
  \chemmove{
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
       \left\delimleft
         \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
       \right.
      $};
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
        \left.
          \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
        \right\delimright_{\rlap{#3}}
      $};
  }%
}

%
%----------------------------end of preamble---------------------------------
%
\begin {document}

\setpolymerdelim() \chemfig{[:-30]*6((-C(-[:240]Cl 
[@{op,.25}]
)(=[:120]O))=-=(-C(-[:300]OCH_2CH_2-O-[@{cl,.25}]H)(=[:60]O))-=-)} \makebraces(35pt,15pt){$\!\!{\rm n}$}{op}{cl}


\end {document}
```

Which gives me this image:

[image]

If anyone is familiar with parenthesis in `chemfig`, please run the code and see if you could answer for me? I would be much obliged!

Could I get some help tidying up the position of the left hand bracket and getting rid of the little box after the Cl?

***Thanks for the responses but to clarify,, what I am trying to achieve is the following***

[image]

Comment: By the way: Welcome to TeX.SX! :) You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typed `\chemfig{...Cl[@{op,.25}]...}` which implies an optional argument to the »Cl« atom. There are no optional arguments to atoms, though! This means `chemfig` interprets the quare brackets as atoms, i.e., it typesets them. This leads to the “little box” you see.

There are two legal places for the `@{...}` syntax:

> - a zero size node on a bond using the syntax “`@{<name>,<coeff>}`”
>     placed at the beginning of the optional argument of the relevant bond,
>     without being followed by a comma if there is a first optional
>     argument. In this case, the node takes the name “`<name>`” and the
>     `<coeff>`, which must be between `0` and `1`, determines where the node is
>     located on the bond. If “`@{<name>}`” is used, the `<coeff>` is set to `0.5`
>     by default, which means that the node is placed halfway along the
>     bond;
> - a node on an atom using the syntax “`@{<name>}`” immediately
>     before the relevant atom. In this case, the node has exactly the same
>     footprint as the atom, but may be empty and therefore have zero
>     dimensions.

So with `\chemfig{...Cl[@{op,.25}]...}` you have effectively marked the closing square bracket.

Solution: add a bond in front of the square brackets `\chemfig{...Cl-[@{op,.25}]...}`.

The rest is fine (it looks like the macros copied from the documentation). You'll only have to play with the `<coeff>` and the values of the `(#1,#2)` argument to `\makebraces`.

Also have a look at [How to draw parentheses inside chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96633/how-to-draw-parentheses-inside-chemfig)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}

%these for bonds in chemfig
\setdoublesep{0.35700 em}  % 'Bond Spacing'
\setatomsep{1.78500 em}    % 'Fixed Length'
\setbondoffset{0.18265 em} % 'Margin Width'
\newcommand{\bondwidth}{0.06642 em} % 'Line Width'
\setbondstyle{line width = \bondwidth}

%Drawing parentheses around polymers
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}

\def\makebraces(#1,#2)#3#4#5{%
  \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
  \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
  \chemmove{
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
       \left\delimleft
         \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
       \right.
      $};
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
        \left.
          \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
        \right\delimright_{\rlap{#3}}
      $};
  }%
}

%
%----------------------------end of preamble---------------------------------
%
\begin {document}

\setpolymerdelim()

\chemfig{
  [:-30]*6(
    (-C
      (-[@{op,.7}:225,2]Cl)
      (=[:120]O)
    )=-=(-C
      (-[:300]OCH_2CH_2-O-[@{cl,.25}]H)
      (=[:60]O)
    )-=-
  )
}

\makebraces(45pt,15pt){$\!\!{n}$}{op}{cl}

\end {document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this is what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}

%these for bonds in chemfig
\setdoublesep{0.35700 em}  % 'Bond Spacing'
\setatomsep{1.78500 em}    % 'Fixed Length'
\setbondoffset{0.18265 em} % 'Margin Width'
\newcommand{\bondwidth}{0.06642 em} % 'Line Width'
\setbondstyle{line width = \bondwidth}

%Drawing parentheses around polymers
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}

\def\makebraces(#1,#2)#3#4#5{%
  \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
  \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
  \chemmove{
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
       \left\delimleft
         \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
       \right.
      $};
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
        \left.
          \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
        \right\delimright_{\rlap{#3}}
      $};
  }%
}

%
%----------------------------end of preamble---------------------------------
%
\begin {document}

\setpolymerdelim() \chemfig{[:-30]*6((-C(-[:240]Cl-[@{op,0.2},,,,draw=none]
)(=[:120]O))=-=(-C(-[:300]OCH_2CH_2-O-[@{cl,.25}]H)(=[:60]O))-=-)} \makebraces(45pt,15pt){$\!\!\textrm{n}$}{op}{cl}

\end {document}
```

[image]