# Create with chemfig a repeating unit of Si-O

Tags: chemfig

I want to recreate this picture found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone_rubber#/media/File:Pdms.png), but with only the group in the parentheses.[image: Repeating unit of silicone rubber]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96634/5049

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I looked at that one and I'm trying to implement it, but I don't have a clue how the chemfig syntax works. I'm currently doing `\chemfig{Si-[:30]O-[:-30]Si}` but it doesn't look good and it's missing the empty carbon bonds

Comment: The syntax of `chemfig` is explained in detail in the `chemfig` manual?!

Comment: Naturally, but I would rather have someone explain it for me. But I'll try and then post my answer. Oh well.

Comment: Which aspects of the syntax should we explain? If there are details of the syntax you don't understand you should ask questions about those details. the someone can add an answer explaining said details. Explaining the whole syntax would otherwise require to more or less repeat the whole manual…

Comment: I already explained the details about the `\makebraces` macro and how to use it in the answer I linked. If you have concrete questions about that I can also answer them. Otherwise I'd just reproduce my answer here (exchanging `C` with `Si` and `O`…)

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the braces.

Comment: I do now realise I malformed my question, sorry for that! The real title should be ***Create with chemfig one unit of Si-O***

Comment: So you want this: `\chemfig{-[:30]Si(-[:90])(-[:-90])-[:-30]O-[:30]}` where branches are inserted in between braces?

Comment: Yes, I've marked @MarcoG's answer.after his edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get this output with this code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}

% Set chemical bonds length
\setatomsep{20pt}

% From chemfig manual
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}
\def\makebraces(#1,#2)#3#4#5{%
  \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
  \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
  \chemmove{
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
       \left\delimleft
         \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
       \right.
      $};
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$
        \left.
          \vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
        \right\delimright_{\rlap{#3}}
      $};
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\setpolymerdelim()

\chemfig{-[:-30,0.7]Si(-[:90,0.7])(-[:-90,0.7])-[:30]O-[@{op,.5}:-30]Si(-[:90,0.7])(-[:-90,0.7])-[:30]O-[@{cl,.5}:-30]Si(-[:90,0.7])(-[:-90,0.7])-[:30,0.7]}

\makebraces(10pt,20pt){$\!\!\!n$}{op}{cl}

\end{document}
```

That produces:

[image]

As you can see, I took the code for the brackets from [`chemfig` manual](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig_doc_en.pdf) (part III, section 12.5). I adjusted the length of the empty bonds with `-[:<angle>,<length multiplier>]`.

**EDIT:** If you want to get only one Si-O group like the following:

[image]

You only need this code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}

% Set chemical bonds length
\setatomsep{20pt}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{-[:-30,0.7]Si(-[:90,0.7])(-[:-90,0.7])-[:30]O-[:-30,0.7]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll use this in my document. However my question was for the part enclosed by the parentheses. I'll mark this as the answer if you add the same formula for n=1. (Only one Si-O)

Comment: @Emilgardis Do you mean e.g. only the first Si-O group, without brackets? I'll edit my answer in a moment.